# How to replace line number in a python logging function

Tags: python, django, logging

I have a method that I am calling at the end of all my django views for logging.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def context_logger(context, request):
    for key, val in context.items():
        if key is not 'page_form' and key is not 'failure_form':
            logger.debug('%s - context for %s: %s', request.get_full_path(), key, val)
            logger.debug(sys._getframe().f_lineno)
```

views

```
def index(request):
    products, tools = menu()
    job_executions = jobs_in_progress()
    context = {"products": products, "tools": tools, "job_executions": job_executions}
    context_logger(context, request)

    # i am able to get the line number here
    logger.debug(sys._getframe().f_lineno)
    return render(request, "app/index.html", context)
```

The problem is when context_logger gets called it always prints the line number of the context_logger method (rather than where it is being called from) in the log.

I am able to grab the line # with

```
(sys._getframe().f_lineno)
```

but not sure how to replace this in the log.

Is there a straight forward way to do this?

If I do something like (sys._getframe().f_lineno) = actual_line_number
I get this error:

```
ValueError: f_lineno can only be set by a line trace function
```

Comment: Maybe a more direct question to ask is where is django settings getting %(lineno)s from?  How can I override this value, ultimately that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Would I be better off turning this function into a django logging filter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm very intersted in this question as well, unfortunately it seems impossible. While setting up a log record, the python logger accepts the dict `extra` to add information to that record (see `Lib/logging/__init__.py`). Unfortunately the logger methods like `.info(msg)` do not accept a similar option AND changing the line number will raise an exception, as the key will already be present (see `Lib/logging/__init__.py 1252 ff`):

```
rv = LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)
if extra is not None:
  for key in extra:
    if (key in ["message", "asctime"]) or (key in rv.__dict__):
      raise KeyError("Attempt to overwrite %r in LogRecord" % key)
    rv.__dict__[key] = extra[key]
```

I'm very curious if anybody has an idea, why the developers did not allow the manipulation of the logger (if it was an purpose or just not important enough).